# How to send and receive JSON data between two servers via php

Tags: php, json, post, laravel, laravel-4

Obviously I am not using the right keywords in my searches or am not understanding what others have written in blogs or forums, et al.

Looking for information on passing data between two servers. The data will be preferably contained within a JSON array.
If you know of someone who has written a blog fully encompassing this I would really like a chance to read it. Otherwise could you offer some thoughts?

More detailed:
As a user visits a page a PHP function will be called and some data will be "packaged up" in a JSON array and then a POST command to the other server. The second server after receiving the POST will do some processing and then "package up" some data and return it in a JSON array. Then the user will be presented with the results.

With the following I am receiving a HTTP 200 response. Just no data.

**SITE 1:**

```
$data_string = json_encode(array('user_id'=>123));
$ch = curl_init('http://site2.dev/retrieve');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
        ));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($result);
```

**SITE 2:**

```
public function retrieve() {
    return json_encode(array('some'=>'456'));
}
```

The Json array was chosen as it can be encrypted and yes HTTPS will be used in the final environment.

Both servers will have Laravel 4 as the PHP Framework.

Thank you for your thoughts and comments.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong except I don't think you're supposed to set Content-Length yourself. What do your routes look like?

Comment: Site 1 routes.php Route::get('/','AccountController@getHome'); and Site 2 routes.php Route::get('retrieve','ProcessController@retrieve');

Comment: Your site 2 route is `GET` but you're sending `POST` from site 1.

Comment: Thanks @takteek. I did update it to Route::post('retrieve','ProcessController@retrieve'); Still the same response. HTTP code 200 and no data returned.

Comment: You can sent Content-Length yourself, but it's tricky to make the value accurate.  It can vary depending on the encoding, use of compression, etc.  It would be best to remove that part of your code and let the web browser add it automatically if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

and put quotes on content-length:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array('Content-Type: application/json','"Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string) . '"'));
```